# How to rebind "special meaning" of C-u to a different key?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

Excerpt from GNU Emacs manual:

```
C-u alone has the special meaning of “four times”: 
it multiplies the argument for the next command by four. 
C-u C-u multiplies it by sixteen.
Thus, C-u C-u C-f moves forward sixteen characters.
```

Is there a way to get this multiplication by sixteen when rebinding `universal-argument` to a different key? I did the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'universal-argument)
```

But when I press `C-i C-i a` only 4 copies of `a` are inserted, not 16 (if I rebind `universal-argument` back to `C-u` then I get 16 copies as advertised in the manual).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add *at least* one additional definition:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'universal-argument)

(define-key universal-argument-map (kbd "C-i") 'universal-argument-more)
```

See additional `universal-...` definitions in *both* `bindings.el` and `simple.el` that may be rebound if so desired.